# Generate starter code based on new file VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure some code based on a file extension when created in VS Code? I'm currently working with [psioniq file header](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=psioniq.psi-header&ssr=false#overview) which has been pretty helpful in generating good header files, but I'm looking to take this a step farther.

When I create a new file, based on a specific file extension, I would like it to generate some starting code that I can configure. For example, I work with Verilog a lot. It would be really cool if Code could generate based on the file name.

1. Create new file
2. Code generates some code (like below) or something else that could be configured based on the filetype:

```
module <filename> (
  input ,
  output ,
);

endmodule
```

Anyone have any extensions they know about or resources they can point me to to implement this?

Comment: you can use the same prefix for all the files, because they are defined for a particular language. Emmet uses `!` for html

Answer (score 1):

This would be a pretty easy extension to write but an alternative is snippets.

You can create keywords, based on the extensions, that when you type it it'll create all that code for you.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: snippets are arguably a better solution than code templates because the snippet can also place a cursor where you want it, allow you to tab through and do substitutions, etc.